# Laurent Series Of $\frac{z}{(z+1)(z+2)}$ Around $z=-1$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Expand $\frac{z}{(z+1)(z+2)}$ Around $z=-1$

$$\frac{z}{(z+1)(z+2)}=-\frac{1}{z+1}+\frac{2}{z+2}=-(z+1)^{-1}+\frac{2}{z+2}=\\=-(z+1)^{-1}+\frac{2}{1-(-z-1)}=-(z+1)^{-1}+2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(z+1)^n$$

Can I write all inside the sum operator? the first terms are:

$\frac{-1}{(z+1)}+2-2(z+1)+2(z+1)^2+...$

So the function as a simple pole and the radius of convergence is
$lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{|\sqrt[n]{(-1)^n}|}=1$

So $|z+1|<1$ and on $|z+1|=1$ we get $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n$ which diverges?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @anomaly if I can write all as $\sum a_n (z+1)^n$ if the radius of convergence is $|z+1|<1?$

Comment: Sure, why not?$\phantom{}$

Comment: @Bernard Are you sure about the partial fractions decomposition? how can I write it within a sum

Comment: @newhere: Sorry, I hadn't checked with pencil and paper. Something looked weird to me, but I was wrong. Sorry for the trouble, I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @Bernard no prob, you are allowed to have some mistakes :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps would be simpler using $w=z+1$ then
\begin{align}
\frac{z}{(z+1)(z+2)}
&=\frac{w-1}{w(w+1)}\\
&=\frac{w-1}{w}\frac{1}{1+w}\\
&=\frac{1-w}{-w}\left(1-w+w^2-w^3+\cdots\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{-w}\left(1-2w+2w^2-2w^3+\cdots\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{w}+2-2w+2w^2-2w^3+\cdots\\
&=-\frac{1}{z+1}+2-2(z+1)+2(z+1)^2-2(z+1)^3+\cdots
\end{align}

Comment: Always good to have another way, but it still not within one sum (aka $\sum a_n(z+1)^n$

Answer (score 2):

Your Laurent Series is correct. $$\frac{z}{(z+1)(z+2)}=-(z+1)^{-1}+2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}(z+1)^n$$
You have to be careful about the region of convergence which is $0<|z+1|<1$